# Is it possible to use app to add NFC Mifare card to the wallet on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, nfc

[The Wallet app steps to add the card on developer](https://developer.apple.com/wallet/get-started/)

[And it says also can pass the nfc info.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/walletpasses/pass/nfc)

So I want to ask if it is possible to save the card with NFC info like Mifare Classic 1k Card with card id and the Sector into the wallet.
And realize mifare card emulation on ios.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is no, not possible.

The Mifare Classic 1k Card is a propitiatory format card and does not conform to the NFC Forum Standards. All card emulation is done using NFC Forum Type 4 card emulation.